# Como remover uma foreign key no mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Preciso editar uma tabela, mas não posso remove-la. Necessito da remoção da foreign key, porém, todos os comandos que tentei não funcionaram.

Estou tentanto atualmente o

```
alter table tabela drop foreign key nomefk
```

e sempre acontece o erro dizendo que não existe nenhuma chave estrangeira, porém, quando puxo no describe, ela existe e impede que eu modifique a tabela. Descrevendo melhor que vou fazer, essa tabela originalmente era uma relação 1 para N, porém analisei melhor o problema e agora virou N para N e por isso necessito remover essa chave para cria-la na tabela adicional.

Comment: Tentou usando o phpmyadmin?

Comment: A FK não está em uma outra tabela que referencia essa que você quer editar?

Comment: Pode colar o o sql de construção da base de dados  e indicar o nome da tabela e foreign que está a tentar remover.

Comment: já tentou isso:`alter table nome_tabela DROP COLUMN nomefk`

Answer (score 2):

O comando deve ser:

`alter table` tabela `drop foreign key` nomefk

O que está acontecendo é que ele não está encontrando o nome da foreign key, pois o nome pode ter uma alteração automática do MySQL quando é criado. O próprio MySQL faz a alteração.
O que você deve fazer é achar o nome correto da `foreing key` e depois executar o comando.
Para achar o nome da fk abra a aba `Schemas` que fica na parte debaixo do lado esquerdo da tela inicial do banco de dados, clique com o botão direito do mouse sobre a `tabela` que está a fk, depois clica em `Alter Table`. Na tela seguinte procure na parte debaixo a aba `Foreing Keys`. Nessa aba vai aparecer o campo `Foreing Key Name`. Você usa este nome no comando `alter table` tabela `drop foreign key` nomefk. OK

Answer (score 0):

DJM_JM, testei seu comando no banco criado com o script a seguir:

```
    mysql> CREATE DATABASE teste;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE `logins` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `nome` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected

mysql> use teste;
Database changed
mysql>  CREATE TABLE `logins` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `nome` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

Query OK, 0 rows affected (2.35 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE `posts` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `logins_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `texto` text,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `fk_posts` (`logins_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_posts` FOREIGN KEY (`logins_id`) 
    REFERENCES `logins` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

Query OK, 0 rows affected (1.61 sec)

mysql> alter table posts drop foreign key fk_posts;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (2.54 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Note que deu certo. Veja se não há duplicação de chave ou erro nos nomes das tabelas.

Comment: Não há duplicidade de chaves. A tabela possui apenas uma coluna com a FK e o erro que informa é que não encontra a a coluna na tabela. Fiz o teste com describe mais uma e a foreign key está lá.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta corrigir, senão desiste e dá outra solução...

**Tentativa de correção**

```
DELIMITER \\

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0\\

ALTER TABLE tabela DROP FOREIGN KEY nomefk\\

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1\\

DELIMITER ;
```

**Não deu? Refaz tudo com o seguinte:**

```
DELIMITER \\

--crie uma tebale temporária com a mesma estrutura da outra, mas sem chave primária
CREATE TABLE tabela_tmp (colunas, etc)\\

--passa os dados da 'tabela' para a 'tabela_tmp'
SELECT INTO  tabela_tmp  (colunas, etc) ...
 SELECT FROM tabela\\

-- detorna a tabela anterior
DROP TABLE tabela\\

-- coloca a tabela tmp com o mesmo nome da que vc detonou anteriormente
RENAME TABLE tabela_tmp TO tabela\\

-- coloca a Foreign Key de novo (consulta syntax no site)
ALTER TABLE TABELA
    ADD fk_nome FOREIGN KEY (etc, ...) \\

DELIMITER ;
```